# Doctrine DateInterval in QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dateinterval, doctrine-extensions

Doctrine 2 supports FieldType "interval" and it is stored in DB as varchar "+P00Y00M168DT00H00M00S"

For Entity's this is enough to add this to an DateTime-Object.

But i wonder why this can't used in QueryBuilder. 
Should i create a Custom DQL-Function for Query?